# c++ read flash AIR NativeAplication arguments

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, air

Hy I have made an AIR application that uses the flash.desktop.NativeProcess to start an c++ a* pathsolver. The reason being - Flash needs too much time to solve 250 * 250 open grid.

The AIR app is fine. It can start the c++ exe file 
The exe fine works on its own

The problem is. They don't work in pair :(

When flash sends the arguments the c++ part just dies silently

```
char buf[ 256 ]; std::cin.getline( buf, 256 );
```

I just havent mannaged to find wat is going on. If i use arguments insted of standard imput i get some strange characters. Any idea ?

Comment: **Flash needs too much time to solve 250 * 250 open grid.** Too much time is how much time? Are you really sure that A* you have is really optimized? 10 years ago I had some experience optimizing Wave pathfinding in AS3, and it was literally hundreds (no kidding) times faster with all AS3 nuances taken into account rather than coded by the book. Anyway, even if the only fast way there is, indeed, the use of C++, you'd rather do it as ANE, not as EXE subprocess.

Comment: Well  the AS3 A* code was done by folowing the tutorial, and it was not optimised. I managed to make it faster a little bit. The problem is when you request the path from one side of the map to another. There are to much iterations. It takes AS3 about 40 seconds per bot.  The c++ on the other hand takes 0.1 second

Comment: Yeah it's not Air that's slow, it's your code. Air gives you great access to all of the client's cpu, gpu, and memory. Post your code.

Comment: [link](https://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2010/08/20/introduction-to-a-a-star-pathfinding-in-actionscript-3-as3-2/) You can se the code here. I followed the tutorial.

Comment: I tend to agree with **moot**. It's not that AS3 cannot handle pathfinding on a large map, it's that code that creates a huge load of nodes with these getter/setter properties. It's correct algorithmically, but it's like opposite of efficiency. Especially if you went along with the tutorial and have your nodes to be objects with getter/setter properties. So, if you would care to post the input data you have, I'll check if my Wave is fast enough. The backup plan - ANE. Because EXE solution has flaws (and it doesn't work anyway).

Comment: Oh, trust me :) I have fate in AIR. That is why I am developing a 62500 *4 tiles per level - ISO RPG using it :) Its just that I figured out I will do a separate tread app for pathfinding. 1. I want atleast 30 fps 2. This is going to be a mass annihilation game. For now I will use the ugly hack that I wrote below. Just to keed development up to date. At end fase I will convert the solution to ANE

Comment: Still, I'd like you to provide the input data, if you don't mind? I'm kind of interested.

Comment: _______x___xxx____xx__________xx

Comment: Basically you can see the pattern in previous comment. That goes on and on 250 *250 * 4. Its a forest with lots of trees. Its not a maze ... Lots of reconsideration for the algorithm. I can't post the code. Its a whole game with hundreds of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well then. You will find the working (furthermore, working fast) wave pathfinding demo below. There are two test cases:

- 32x32 predesigned dungeon, loops 256 times, runs 0.12s - 0.13s
- 320x320 big, empty, entrance and exit are at opposite corners, runs 0.03s - 0.04s

So, the problem with the tutorials and algorithms that they are ideal for clean small tutorial cases. When there are a lot of data, well, not so much. If you'd followed that tutorial, it leaves you with that **Node** class of getters and setters. Each time you refer a getter or setter, you invoke a function call, which is a relatively heavy operation. One time, ten times, hundred times - no problem, but there you have 64K of those nodes, that builds the performance momentum. Even if you didn't go for getter/setter picture, there are still a lot of node instances, you pull their properties... you get the picture, right?

When I first did that wave pathfinding in 2009, I too did blunder into the mess of node instances and their properties. Then 2-dimensional array of ints, no good. Then I thought of **BitmapData** class which could quite literally represent the map and hold 32 bits of data per cell/pixel. Every one idea turned out to still be too slow.

I might've possibly thought of 1-dimensional representation faster, but the thing is, I worked with hexagonal map so each cell had 6 ways out, not just 4, a bit confusing.

Yet, in the end, I came up with the whole idea of mapping the area into 1-dimensional array and navigating it with **+1**, **-1**, **+width** and **-width** shifts (well, 2 more for hexagonal topography). I had no need of complicated things back then (and I don't think you need them either) like path weights, just to find the shortest path in an UX-acceptable time frame.

If you look at the algorithms pathfinding part, it's so simple. No **x** and **y** coordinates. No border checks. No node objects, no properties, no additional function calls. Just the simplest math and a few operations per each cell - as few as it possible. That's why it is so fast and efficient.

The mentioned **Log** class, you can grab it at [my repo](https://bitbucket.org/thydmitry/ru.delimiter/src/2756fadd741a6d44276fde1701470daf24cebfa8/classes/ru/delimiter/utils/Log.as?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

```
package
{
    import flash.utils.getTimer;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import ru.delimiter.utils.Log;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Dmitry Yamaykin
     */

    public class PathFinding extends Sprite
    {
        public function PathFinding() 
        {
            super();

            // Log is a debug output panel which allows you
            // to see things if traces are unavailable
            // or/and suppressed by the release build.
            Log.create(this, true);
            Log.log("[PathFinding] starts!");

            testBig();
            testSmall();
        }

        // The main data array that keeps obstacles,
        // empty cells and those already passed by the wave.
        private var map:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>;

        // The front of the wave and the next front.
        private var wave:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>;
        private var froth:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>;

        // Mapping the map back to the original data. Just for
        // this demo, you probably won't need it with the real thing.
        private var route:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>;

        // Be extra careful with the 'w' argument, if you fumble with
        // the width of the row, the whole thing will totally go astray.
        private function findPath(source:Array, w:int, h:int):Array
        {
            var length:int = source.length;
            var begin:int;
            var end:int;
            var i:int;

            var steps:int;
            var windex:int;
            var findex:int;
            var mindex:int;

            map.fixed = false;
            wave.fixed = false;
            froth.fixed = false;
            route.fixed = false;

            // The brilliance of it: working with just a few instances
            // that are set up in the very beginning and fixed to a
            // certain amount of memory. No memory management while
            // finding paths, no creating and disposing of instances,
            // no Garbage Collector to kick in and do its thing.

            map.length = length;
            wave.length = w + h;
            froth.length = w + h;
            route.length = length;

            map.fixed = true;
            wave.fixed = true;
            froth.fixed = true;
            route.fixed = true;

            // The main idea behind fast wave is mapping the source
            // 2-dimensional data into 1-dimensional array of int
            // values. Your position is indicated by a single
            // index, +1 is 'go right', -1 is 'go left',
            // +width and -width are 'go down' and 'go up' respectively.
            // Just don't forget to add a solid impassable top and bottom
            // lines (to avoid 'out of range' array errors) and a solid
            // wall at the right (at least) so you don't flip over the
            // data while going right from the rightmost position
            // and left from the leftmost. It's far more efficient this
            // way than additional code checks for borders.

            for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                switch (source[i])
                {
                    case '.':
                        map[mindex] = 0;
                        route[mindex] = i;

                        mindex++;
                        break;

                    case '#':
                        map[mindex] = -1;
                        route[mindex] = i;

                        mindex++;
                        break;

                    case 'X':
                        map[mindex] = -1;
                        route[mindex] = i;
                        end = mindex;

                        mindex++;
                        break;

                    case 'Y':
                        // We need it to be passable
                        // for wave to wash in there.
                        map[mindex] = 0;
                        route[mindex] = i;
                        begin = mindex;

                        mindex++;
                        break;
                }
            }

            // Be careful with logging. It duplicates the output to the
            // standard trace, which includes writing to a file
            // (Flash thing, not my fault) which is really,
            // like REALLY slow operation to do.

            // Log.log(begin, '>', end);

            // With just fixed [1, -1, w, -w] it will work a bit faster,
            // bit the algorithm will prefer going in the straight lines,
            // rather than wandering in diagonals and cutting the corners.

            var AWX:int = 0;
            var AWAY:Array;
            var WAYS:Array =
            [
                [1, -1, w, -w],
                [w, -w, 1, -1],
                [-1, w, 1, -w],
                [-w, 1, w, -1],

                [1, -1, -w, w],
                [w, -w, -1, 1],
                [-1, 1, -w, w],
                [w, -w, -1, 1],

                [1, w, -1, -w],
                [w, -1, -w, 1],
                [-1, 1, w, -w],
                [-w, w, 1, -1],

                [1, -w, -1, w],
                [w, 1, -w, -1],
                [-1, -w, 1, w],
                [w, -1, -w, 1],
            ];

            // Lets the party begin.
            wave[0] = end;
            windex = 1;

            // Repeat while wave front is not empty.
            while (windex)
            {
                // Pick the next pattern of motion preferences.
                if (--AWX < 0) AWX = WAYS.length - 1;

                AWAY = WAYS[AWX];

                // Go through all the points on the current wave front.
                while (windex--)
                {
                    var anindex:int = wave[windex];

                    // Try to move into the all
                    // possible directions from it.
                    for each (var ashift:int in AWAY)
                    {
                        // This value will be used a few times
                        // so it's better to calculate it once and store.
                        var awindex:int = anindex + ashift;

                        // Either -1 (impassable) or 1+
                        // (wave's been here already) means
                        // this spot is of no interest to us.
                        if (map[awindex]) continue;

                        // The 'path is found' routine.
                        if (awindex == begin)
                        {
                            // Log.log("THE WAY");

                            // The following code is just a dummy demo.
                            var result:Array = source.slice();

                            while (anindex != end)
                            {
                                result[route[anindex]] = '*';
                                anindex = map[anindex];
                            }

                            return result;

                            /**
                             * The main idea behind the result code
                             * is to unwind the calculated path,
                             * which is pretty easy because each
                             * affected map cell contains
                             * the index of the previous
                             * cell all the way back
                             * to the center of
                             * the wave.
                             * 

                            result = [begin];

                            while (anindex != end)
                            {
                                result.push(anindex);
                                anindex = map[anindex];
                            }

                            result.push(end);

                             *
                            **/
                        }

                        // Add the empty cell to the
                        // next front line of the wave.
                        map[awindex] = anindex;
                        froth[findex++] = awindex;
                    }
                }

                // The next front line is formed,
                // time to move on to the next iteration.

                var xchange:Vector.<int> = froth;
                var xindex:int = findex;

                froth = wave;
                findex = 0;

                wave = xchange;
                windex = xindex;

                //Log.log(windex, wave);
            }

            // If we're here, that means the wave started
            // at the 'end' point never hit the 'begin'.

            trace("NO WAY");

            return null;
        }

        // Tests pathfinding in a smaller dungeon: a multiple times.
        private function testSmall():void
        {
            var X:XML = <root><![CDATA[
                ##################################
                #.............#................#Y#
                #.....#.......#.......#........#.#
                #.....#.......#.......#........#.#
                #.....#.......#.......#........#.#
                #.....#.......#.......#........#.#
                #.....#.......#.......#........#.#
                #.....#.......#.......#........#.#
                #.....#.......#.......#........#.#
                #.....#.......#.......#........#.#
                #.....#...............#..........#
                #.....############################
                #................................#
                #................................#
                #................................#
                #................................#
                #######..........................#
                #................................#
                #...####.........................#
                #................................#
                #................................#
                #................................#
                #................................#
                #................................#
                #................................#
                #................................#
                ##################...............#
                #................#...............#
                #................#...............#
                #...######.......#...............#
                #........#.......#...............#
                #........#.......#...............#
                #........#.......#...............#
                #X.......#.......................#
                ##################################
            ]]></root>;

            var D:String = X.children()[0].toString().split("\r").join("");
            var A:Array = D.split("");

            var aTime:int = getTimer();

            var R:Array;

            for (var i:int = 255; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                R = findPath(A, 34, 34);
            }

            Log.log("");
            Log.log("32 x 32, pre-designed, not empty, 256 times.");
            Log.log("Elapsed", getTimer() - aTime, "ms.");

            if (R) Log.log(R.join(""));
        }

        // Tests pathfinding in a big empty dungeon.
        private function testBig():void
        {
            var D:String = "";

            // Lets form a biiig empty field with
            // entrance and exit at the opposite corners.
            var TB:String = G("#", 322);
            var TX:String = "#" + G(".", 319) + "X#";
            var TY:String = "#Y" + G(".", 319) + "#";
            var TE:String = "#" + G(".", 320) + "#";

            D += TB;
            D += TX;

            for (var i:int = 0; i < 318; i++)
            {
                D += TE;
            }

            D += TY;
            D += TB;

            var A:Array = D.split("");
            var aTime:int = getTimer();

            var R:Array = findPath(A, 320, 320);

            Log.log("");
            Log.log("320 x 320, empty.");
            Log.log("Elapsed", getTimer() - aTime, "ms.");
        }

        private function G(char:String, repeat:int):String
        {
            var result:String = char;

            while (result.length < repeat)
            {
                result += result;
            }

            result = result.substr(0, repeat);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: :) That is a great demo :) I will most definitely consider your algorithm. It will save me time with packaging the app, and AV checks. There is nothing more that any AV program likes than to stop the triggered exe for a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly hack, but does the job :D

```
var f = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("command.txt"); 
var stream = new FileStream();
stream.open(f, FileMode.WRITE);  
stream.writeUTFBytes(nextQuery.command + "/" + nextQuery.data);
stream.close();
```

You can guess the c++ side

```
std::stringstream strmap;
strmap << my_documents << "/command.txt" ;
std::ifstream myfile (strmap.str().c_str());
```

I call it the

> black market algorytm